# ip-based popup for language selection

Tags: routes, ip, country

we are looking for a solution wo popup a small language / country selection feature, similar to boots.com where you can select to stay on the uk website or select any other language or country.

the user should have the opportunity to select his country/language based on ip or the english version of the site.

do you know any service / API who can handle such requests externally?

brgds
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to base some decision on the country your client is connecting from. This is called [geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation) and there are many services and APIs to do that, including [browser-based (HTML5) geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).

Note also that selection of user *language* can (should?) be based not on the user *location*, but on his preferred *language* instead; there is a HTTP header exactly for that purpose: [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4).

But no, I don’t know any service which would provide the whole solution as an external service that you could just plug into your website.